# get output volume with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, sound-volume

I'm writing an AppleScript which should show the value for the output volume. With `get volume settings` I'm getting 4 values, but I need just the output volume value. The integer should be shown in a `display dialog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

```
display alert output volume of (get volume settings)
```